# Connecting nexus with ubuntu not working properly

Tags: usb

I'm trying to connect my Nexus 4 with Ubuntu 13.10 via USB. But the device is reconnecting every second (and opening nautilus every time).
If I leave the device connected it opens infinitely many nautilus windows!?
Does anyone know what might cause the problem?